# How to filter data before pagination flutter firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I'm making a rental car application. I'm getting data with pagination (limit 3) filtering them for price descending however at some cases, companies can offer discounts. When this happens, my database filtering becomes ineffective. For example there are 4 cars in database (40$, 50$, 60$, 70$). When I filter data with this code :

```
var availableCars = await _firestore
        .collection('carMini')
        .where('locations', arrayContains: order.address)
        .orderBy('carPrice', descending: false)
        .limit(3)
        .get();
```

Even if the discounted price of the 4th car is lower than others,
This price appears later because the data comes with pagination.
Is there any way I can pre-set this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way for a Firestore query to filter on such a calculated value. The only way to get a single query working, is to also store the effective/discounted price in a separate field and order/filter on that.

```
var availableCars = await _firestore
    .collection('carMini')
    .where('locations', arrayContains: order.address)
    .orderBy('discountedCarPrice')
    .limit(3)
    .get();
```

Comment: The discounted price varies with each car from condition to condition. These conditions are also specified when searching. how can i do this dynamically?

Comment: Or i can remove pagination and get all cars in this location. Do you think pagination is that important for such an application?

Comment: Pagination is overvalued in many apps, but that's just my opinion. You will have to determine whether you need pagination. To your "how can i do this dynamically?": conditions can only evaluate against values stored in the documents they're querying (so `carMini` in your case). You will have to store the values you want to query against in each document, such as I did with `discountedCarPrice` in my answer.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. There were places where I used pagination, but I chose not to use it here.